# How to test IIS Kerberos Authentication on local machine when developer has no permissions to AD

Tags: iis-7, kerberos, service-principal

I have a web application that I am switching to use Kerberos Authentication. I do not have access to the AD to create a SPN. I tried to create a SPN locally to no avail, and according to the answer in [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/f946912a-9d57-43bb-a648-eed298c2a0f5/spn-configuration?forum=configmgrgeneral) question, it not possible in the first place. Is there any other way to test Kerberos Authentication for a site running in IIS without using SPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. To authenticate against Active Directory you must setup service principle.